# Use template parameter to pass both node type and data type for a linked list

Tags: c++, templates

In my linked list class I want to pass the dataType of the data to store as a template parameter as well as the node type that contains the data, but I keep getting compile error.
Heres the node class
llist.h

```
template<class itemType>
class Node {
    itemType item{};
    Node* next{};
    Node* prev{};
public:
    Node* getnext() { return next; }
    Node* getprev() { return prev; }
    itemType getitem() { return item; }
};
```

and heres the linkedlist class.
llist.h

```
    template <class itemType, class nodeType>
    class LinkedList
    {


//I am trying to say 
//using node=Node<itemType> 
//but dont want to use Node directly and want to get the type of Node from template argument

        using node = nodeType<itemType>;        node* head{};
    public:
        node* getHead() { return head; }
    
    };
```

When I try to instantiate it from main(), I get compiler errors

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    LinkedList<int, Node<int> > list;
    list.getHead();

}
```

Here are the errors:

```
1>X:\code1\Blib\Blib\llist.h(16,23): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
1>C:\code\Blib\Blib\llist.h(21): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'LinkedList<itemType,nodeType>' being compiled
1>C:\code\Blib\Blib\llist.h(16,1): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
1>C:\code\Blib\Blib\llist.h(16,1): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>Done building project "Blib.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `nodeType` as template like `nodeType<itemType>`, you can declare it as [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter).

```
template <class itemType, template <typename> class nodeType>
class LinkedList
```

Then use it like

```
LinkedList<int, Node> list;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gh6kadkLqKpNcd3V)

If you want to declare it as [type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter) as you're doing now, then just use it as

```
template <class itemType, class nodeType>
class LinkedList
{
    using node = nodeType;
    ...
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gBivK9PZhqffzu6q)

Comment: thx, but for this line I am still getting error. using node = nodeType;     1> argument list for template template parameter 'nodeType' is missing

Comment: @bsobaid I added live samples to the answer for reference.

Comment: thx @songyuanyao. This worked. So in both approaches we did'nt have to explicitly specify the template parameter for Node like Node<int>. It deduced its parameter from previous template parameter "int" . LinkedList<int, Node>

Comment: @bsobaid For the 2nd approach you need to specify template argument for `Node` like `Node<int>`. On the other hand you can specify with different type like `LinkedList<int, Node<char> >`. Which one is better depends on your intent.

Answer (score 2):

Template template parameter approach becomes problematic if you have different node types and some of them have additional template parameters. You can also go another way and extract `itemType` type from `Node` instead of passing it to `LinkedList` explicitly. This can be done with `decltype` applied to a member function of `Node`:

```
template<class nodeType>
class LinkedList {
    using itemType = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<nodeType>().getItem())>;
    // ...
};
```

Here [`std::decay_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is used to remove a possible reference from the return type of `getItem()`. In your particular example it returns `itemType`, but in general I would expect `[const] itemType&`.

Alternatively, we can just use a member type in `Node`:

```
template<class itemType>
class Node {
public:
    using type = itemType;
};

template<class nodeType>
class LinkedList {
    using itemType = typename nodeType::type;
    // ...
};
```

Now can write `LinkedList<Node<int>>` and get `itemType` equal to `int`.

Comment: this is also a very scalable and useful approach. Some explaination would have been helpful

Comment: @bsobaid, what kind of explanation?

Comment: nested decltype.     using itemType = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<nodeType>().getItem())>;
but i looked it up.